# Blender wireframe without backface issues

Tags: rendering, wireframe

[image]

Hi I am simply trying to remove the backfaces from my wireframe. The left one has a wireframe material on it. there is my question: How could i integrate an geometry node with "backfacing" as output so that the backfacing side is ignored by the camera?

The right one has a wireframe modifier on it with unchecked "keep original" and a material index of 1.
It has two materials. First one for solids is just transparent. Second one is simply a colour. There as well I wanted to put a geometry info node on the solid onces, so that I can see only the front and make that one transparent.

But I seem to not get it right in this instance, while i could have sworn it was a super easy thing to do.

Could anyone point me to the right way? Better solution? Wireframe with backface culling for rendering. ....

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Eevee:
Your node setup is perfect. Make sure to go to material settings and tick "Backface Culling". And right below that check box is Blend Mode. For Eevee transparency to work, you must change Blend Mode from "Opaque" to "Alpha Blend" or something else.
[image]

If you want to do this in Cycles, you will need this setup:
[image]

Comment: I love this community. I went to bed at 2 AM in the morning, get up at  8 AM and have already two perfect answers. Also, where is the facepalm smiley when you need it. BIG thanks to @Coby Randal! Really appreciated it.

Comment: Also i figured, i had the blending mode wrong. Something I would not have looked for ... I  need to research it a bit i guess. I did set the blend mode to opaque. But with alpha* it works fine in Evee ;) thanks man.

Comment: Oh yeah Im glad you mentioned that; I forgot to mention the Blend Mode in Eevee must be changed from Opaque and set to Alpha Blend or something else. Will update answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

why my wireframe is dividing by additional lines? Could you help me?

[image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/142983)